How do I declare a type for only an object's writable properties?
Here is a very simplified version of the code that I am working on, that aims to create 2 new divs in the X and Y midpoints of the parent div. Ignore that there are far more optimal ways to do this - this is only a snippet of the logic for example purposes.
I'm aiming to save repeat code by iterating over the main logic twice, swapping out 'width' and 'left' for 'height' and 'top' on the second pass through.
const parentDiv = document.querySelector('#parentDiv')!;
const clientRect = parentDiv.getBoundingClientRect();

const clientRectProperties: ReadonlyArray<keyof DOMRect> = ['width', 'height'];
const styleProperties: ReadonlyArray<keyof CSSStyleDeclaration> = ['left', 'top'];

for (let a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
  let midpoint = (clientRect[clientRectProperties[a]] as number) / 2
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.style[styleProperties[a]] = `${midpoint}px`;
  parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
}

The issue lies on line 10, which shows the errors Cannot assign to 'length' because it is a read-only property. and Cannot assign to 'parentRule' because it is a read-only property.
How can I omit read-only properties whilst still ensuring the correct type?

Thanks for the reply @jcalz. I'm not strictly something more elegant or optimal; more wondering if my knowledge of TypeScript was correct. I was curious to see if my approach was more long-winded than necessary due to my lack of knowledge or experience with TypeScript, and if there is a simpler way of acquiring the writeable properties of an object that doesn't feel so 'hacky'. I appreciate the Code Review link though, definitely worth a look at.

Thanks again @jcalz, I appreciate how my post looked originally. I have now provided the code and issue I was having before my attempted fix.

So I'd say the problem is mainly that you have widened your array type too much and TS is worried that its elements are inappropriate for what you're doing. I'd suggest that you use const assertions as shown in this playground link. Then TS knows that styleProperties contains only "left"  and "top", both of which are keys for string-valued props, and it works. You can do the same thing for clientRectProperties and lose the as number. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

That definitely makes sense! Happy for you to write that up, appreciate your patience with this.

The easiest approach here is to use const assertions on your array literals to ask TypeScript to keep track of the literal types of their contents, instead of widening them to string[]:
const clientRectProperties = ['width', 'height'] as const;
// const clientRectProperties: readonly ["width", "height"]
const styleProperties = ['left', 'top'] as const;
// const styleProperties: readonly ["left", "top"]

Your annotations of ReadonlyArray<keyof CSSStyleDeclaration> and ReadonlyArray<keyof CSSStyleDeclaration> are somewhat better than string[], but still too wide for TypeScript to be sure that elements are suitable for your purposes. You could go through the effort of coming up with the full list of suitable elements and then doing that annotation, but it's so much easier to just use a const assertion and let TypeScript know the actual contents of the arrays.
Once you do that, your code works as written, because TypeScript knows that newDiv.style.left and newDiv.style.top accept string values.  And you can even remove the as number type assertion for clientRect[clientRectProperties[a]], since TypeScript knows that clientRect.width and clientRect.height are numbers already:
for (let a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
  let midpoint = (clientRect[clientRectProperties[a]]) / 2 // okay
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.style[styleProperties[a]] = `${midpoint}px`; // okay
  parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
}

Playground link to code
